# What's a dashed line between two classes in UML?

Tags: java, uml, sap-commerce-cloud

The image bellow illustrates a data model of multiple if we could say java classes. I am familliar with all the other type of arrows except the dashed line *marked with red pencil in the image*.

[image]

Comment: I think it is supposed to represent the relation between baseStore and cmsSite. A store can be associated with multiple sites and a site can be associated with multiple stores.

Comment: yes it is right. the issue it that why dashed line instead of a simple line. is the illustration wants to points to sth else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply: nonsense. At least no valid UML. It might be a dependency but then it misses the arrow to show which depends on what.

Further

- the `*` name label is  meaningless.
- The filled arrows are wrong since they are reserved for the `extends`relation used to define stereotypes.
- That dashed line bottom right is invalid as well.

My advice: throw that book where you got that from as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`qwerty_so` gave you an answer related to UML.

In case you are wondering about the technical details of the relationship between BaseStore and CMSSite in Hybris, it's many-to-many.

Answer (score 1):

In UML that dashed line is an anchor, it has no special/strong meaning

A typical/standard use of an anchor is between an element and a note, helping to say the note concerns that element and not an other close to it

In your case its use is obscur, and it is more with the label * as already said

Comment: I know that plain dashes lines are also used to link notes. But I never heard of the term anchor. The specs don't use that  term too. Where is that from? Interestingly I could not find the definition of a note in UML 2.5. Might be the needle in a haystack?

Comment: @qwerty_so I use "anchor" to name the corresponding button in BoUML since the very first version, I did not created that naming so it comes from somewhere. For "note" see _§7.2.4 Notation_ saying _A Comment is shown as a rectangle with the upper right corner bent (this is also known as a "**note** symbol")_. As you know a note can also show a _constraint_

Comment: I see and yes, I know :-) Thanks for the pointer. I remember the drawing but sometimes it's really that needle in a haystack.